# can we install Tableau worker install on same machine where already another tableau Server installed?

Tags: tableau-api

can we install **Tableau worker** install on same machine where already **another tableau Server** installed?

Comment: What do you mean by Tableau worker?

Comment: Another Tableau Cluster/ worker

Answer (score 2):

you can not install tableau worker on the machine which tableau already installed, u need a separate machine to install the Tableau Worker to configure the cluster.